# 特定のカラムの値を一括で nil に変更する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`User`モデルがあり、`has_many :posts`の関係の`Post`モデルが`title`カラムを持ってる時に、
特定のユーザーのタイトルを一括で `nil` に変更したく

```
user.posts.find_each{ |post| post.update(title: nil) }
```

という書き方をしているのですが、もっと効率的な書き方はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update_all` を利用すると、効率的なSQLになります。

```
user.posts.update_all(title: nil)
# UPDATE "posts" SET "title" = NULL WHERE "posts"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
```